# How to do CSS for a grid of images

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, grid

I would like to create a grid of images, and I've met with what I think must be the most common problem for a grid: namely that **how to remove the margin/padding on the last elements?** I was trying (without success):

```
#page {
margin: 0 -8px -8px 0;
}

#page a {
float: left;
margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
```

Why does this code not work? Whats the best way to solve it?

The CSS frameworks forces us to specify the last elements:

960.gs uses:

```
.alpha {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.omega {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

BluePrint CSS uses:

```
.last {margin-right: 0;}
```

Golden Grid uses:

```
.inside {margin-left: 0;}
```

But how can I do it when all I have is a unknown list of images which I would like to put in n-columns? Before, I have written PHP code for this, and I called it with an argument for the number of columns, but there must be some very easy CSS trick for this problem!

(live page link removed, as jsfiddle examples below are much better)

Comment: Sorry it was a typo fixed in a minute, now its fixed. What I want is (for example) to put 3 columns 100 pixel wide images with 10 pixels between them into one div of 320 pixel. The point is that I want the outside div to be 320 pixel instead of 330 pixel wide.

Comment: You mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/9zCdg/) but without the padding around the container?

Comment: The link is still down I'm afraid, if I can see the actual problem I may offer a CSS trick.

Comment: Yes, thats what I wanted and the jsfiddle in your answer is exactly that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is most definitely a simple css/html solution to this. You shouldn't *need* to hardcode the style with php or do math or use javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/34UCn/5/

This may not be the best or only solution, but sometimes adding a wrapper div gives you a lot of flexibility. Here is the important part of the code I used:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <img><img><img><img><img><img>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:320px;
}
.wrapper div {
    /* any width up to (total img width) * (num_columns) */
    /* the rest will be chopped off by overflow:hidden */
    width:330px;

    /* chops off top "padding" of inner div (first row imgs top margin) */
    margin-top:-10px;
}
img {
    width:100px;
    height:75px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Hopefully this the effect you're looking for. This will not work with variable size images, but on your example they all appeared to be the same size. Tested in IE6, IE8 and FF4.

Comment: I should note that the 340px there can just be 330px, mistake. It really doesn't matter though, it just has to be small enough to constrain the number of columns you want.

Comment: THX, its an awesome solution! Yes, its for fixed size thumbnails, of course. But could you explain it in a few words 1. why are two divs needed? 2. why are the top and left sides dealt with in different divs? 3. what is float:left; doing in the 1st div? 4. Do I think it correctly that these two are acting like a .clearfix now?

Comment: I've created a fork (without the top float), and tested this in every possible browser and it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/zsero/34UCn/3/

Comment: Yep no need to float, just my floatitits acting up. It's not the same as a clearfix though. The wrapper was needed for the `overflow:hidden` to chop off the top and right 10px from the img margin. You seem to have it though! Updated post with a new fiddle with a few notes and less css properties.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple CSS solution for this afaik. You either have to use javascript to do some math or use php as you said.

**Edit:** There are selector like `nth-child()`, but I am not sure about compatibility. You can read more about it [**here**](http://24ways.org/2009/cleaner-code-with-css3-selectors) and check the compatibility [**here**](http://www.css3.info/modules/selector-compat/) or just google for more ;) Actually also jQuery is using css selectors, so you can check more examples at [**jQuery api**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Edit2: Uh, I actually forgot, that `nth-child()` is useless anyway, because you don't know `n`. So back to my original answer: **You can't do it without any scripting if you want dynamic behaviour.** You could of course use that nth- selector, but only in case where you know, that you will have some known number of images in one row.

Comment: So what you say is that something like this in PHP `if ($i % 3 == 0) ...` is not as stupid as I thought?

Comment: It's not stupid imo. But there are acutally selectors like nth-child, but I am not sure about browser compatibility. I am going to add two links to my answer so you can try it and get more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
.divclass {
    width:320px;
    float:left;
}
.maincol {
    width:100px;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width-right:10px;
    border-width-left:0px;
    border-width-top:0px;
    border-width-bottom:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.rightcol {
    width:100px;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
<div class="divclass"><!--
--><img class="maincol"><img class="maincol"><img class="rightcol"><br><!--
--><img class="maincol"><img class="maincol"><img class="rightcol"><br><!--
--><img class="maincol"><img class="maincol"><img class="rightcol"><br><!--
--><img class="maincol"><img class="maincol"><img class="rightcol"><br><!--
--><img class="maincol"><img class="maincol"><img class="rightcol"><br><!--
--><img class="maincol"><img class="maincol"><img class="rightcol"><br><!--
--><img class="maincol"><img class="maincol"><img class="rightcol"><br><!--
--><img class="maincol"><img class="maincol"><img class="rightcol"><br><!--
--><img class="maincol"><img class="maincol"><img class="rightcol"><br><!--
--></div>
```

you want NO WHITESPACE CHARACTERS between the images!  those will mess things up...  I am not even sure about comments.